# How can I know if a user exists in my firebase realtime database given a parameter that I send? REACT

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database with React 18. My database has the following structure:

```
- user 
|--> userID 
    |--> _idUser: "adkjaklsd"
    |--> name: "john"
    |--> phone: "12312312" 
|--> userID2 
    |--> _idUser: "adkjaklsd2"
    |--> name: "john 2"
    |--> phone: "12311111"
```

I would like to know if there is a user in my database by passing a phone as a parameter.

I try with the following code:

*I'm already importing correctly the database parameter. userPhone is the number that I want to compare to.*

I'm not sure if I can create queries with Realtime Database, but I found [this information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?hl=en&authuser=0) in the firebase documentation.

```
const existingUser = query(ref(database, '/user/'),equalTo(userPhone));
```

If I print the existingUser query I have the following code in my console:

[image]

I don't know if this result is correct, and if so, how do I handle it?

I try with [onValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=en&authuser=0#web_value_events) as the code below:

```
const userRef = ref(database, '/user/');
      onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const result = data.filter((user) => user.phoneNumber === userPhone);
      });
```

With the code above I am bringing all the data from the database to be able to make a filter with the parameter that I need, but I can't because the data returned by the snapshot.val() is an Object, and **data.filter is not a function**.

Do I need to bring all the data and convert the Object into a array to use **filter**? or Is there any other way to bring this information that I require?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you're using Firestore or Realtime Database.  These are two different databases with different APIs.  Your first code sample is coding against the Firestore API and your second is using RTDB.  The language you're using is also confusing, because Firestore has groupings called "collections", but RTDB does not.  It would help if you edit the question to be perfectly clear about which database you're using, maybe showing a screenshot of the data you're working with.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson thank you for your comment, I'll edit my question with the correct names.